# LINQ include nested properties when selecting anonymous type

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to include the optional `List<Image>` object on each message. I'd prefer to not have to make a round trip to the db for each conversation.

I would normally just select the conversation and use `Include` to include the required properties but that method doesnt support `Take` on a nested collection which is a requirement for my use case.

```
var conversations = await (from c in db.Conversations
          select new {
              conversation = c,
              messages = c.Messages.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreateDate).Take(50)
          }).ToListAsync();
```

Right now the messages do not get the related `List<Image>` object

Comment: Is the anonymous type the problem?  What happens if you `select` into a concrete type instead?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I dont think the anonymous type is involved in the problem really. I couldnt find a way to say 'I am selecting a bunch of objects that together are not reflective of a table in the db'. If I was just selecting 'c' I could use `include` methods to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `messages` be a projection that includes the properties you want:

```
var conversations = await (from c in db.Conversations
      select new {
          conversation = c,
          messages = c.Messages.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreateDate)
             .Select(m => new {message = m, relatedThing = m.RelatedThing})
             .Take(50)
      }).ToListAsync();
```